# Prevent document losing a focus when new tab is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

Let's have a simple code like this:

```
$(e).append(
  $("<a>").attr('href', url)
          .attr('target', '_blank')
          .text(text)
);
```

How can I prevent document losing a focus when new tab is opened?

I want a new tab to be opened in background without switching a focus into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this javascript by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522565/how-to-stay-on-current-window-when-the-link-opens-in-new-tab) question's accepted answer:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

Using the same question's most upvoted answer, try this aswell:

```
<a href="your_url" onclick="window.open('#','_blank');window.open(this.href,'_self');">
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812628/open-a-new-tab-in-the-background) question's accepted answer, try this:

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmvS/5/)

```
function openNewBackgroundTab(){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://www.google.com/";
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Here the tenth parameter sets the `ctrl` key to be true. Then that just acts like a `ctrl` + `click` and then that's opened in an another window without losing focus.

Comment: I don't want to change existing `<a>` code. I am looking for solution that would work with regular standard `href` and `target`.

Comment: @Ωmega try the second example!

Comment: @Ωmega I am continiously adding the links to that answer!

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Chrome, at least not anymore -- [it appears to have been deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent)