# How to stay on current window when the link opens in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

stay in current page but open link in new tab

I want to be in the same/current page but when I click on the link should open in another tab but I should be in the current page

Comment: any help can be appreciable- Thank you

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522565/how-to-stay-on-current-window-when-the-link-opens-in-new-tab

Answer (score 0):

just give attribute to your `a` tag,  `target="_blank"` so browser will always open your link in new tab instead going directly, for example:

```
<a href='http://example.com' target="_blank">
```