# Open href link in new tab but user stayb on current page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open href link in new tab but the user stay on current page

href="/Money/terms" target="_self"  Terms & Conditions

how its possible in HTML??

Comment: can't be done this behavior is control by the browser. take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522565/how-to-stay-on-current-window-when-the-link-opens-in-new-tab)

Comment: Are you trying to have the tab open behind the scenes without being active?  This won't be supported in all browsers. You could probably use some javascript (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924248/2272231) to re-focus the current window.

Answer (score 0):

simply change `target="_self"` to `target="_blank"` inside the anchor:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: Keev!  but user should stay on current page

Comment: yes you can do that by pointing the link to the same page you are already on (  I will edit the reply)

Comment: apperently you have no tried it yet. `target="-blank"  will open the link in a new tab.

Comment: Yes I try with target="_blank" but user not stay on same page

Comment: then see the links above. Its a browser feature. That is the closest you can get to.